# Access unauthenticated while accessing Zendesk ticket api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, zendesk-api

I tried to use Zendesk support API. I able to use those API which has not the only authentication like request API for creating tickets but when I try to use an API that needs to be authenticated, it proved me an HTML page as a response in which "access-unauthenticated" comes as in body class.

I used token authentication in this format

```
https://hello.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json \
   -u hello.kumar@hello.com/token:hmkTUolfojrjugngfm90r595n
```

What am I doing wrong? I am testing the API in Postman.

Comment: Same here. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make sure that the email you are using is a verified user within Zendesk API requests (make sure to try this with a Admin profile). You can authenticate API requests using basic authentication with your email address and password, with your email address and an API token, or with an OAuth access token.

Make sure the API token is still active. Perhaps you could try to regenerate one and then see if that helps. Also, make sure you are using the correct HTTP status method along if you are attempting to GET a ticket or make an update to a ticket.

Cheers,